# iPhone:Teleprompter support

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to provide Teleprompter feature for recorded video ? I allow user to record video from my application, i want to provide Teleprompter feature for the recorded video when user plays back the recorded video. Is there any API or SDK supports it for iPhone 4?
Please guide me if anyone know about it.

Thank you!